# Tomcat Restart required after war file deployment for database connection

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

While deploying a war file (Spring Boot App) on external Tomcat server, I am getting the exception:

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - HikariPool-5 - dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required
```

It gets resolved after server restart and application gets started.

Edit:
Datasource configuration is done as follows:

```
@Bean(name = "datasource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.datasource")
  public DataSource appDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }
```

Properties used:

```
app.datasource.jdbc-url
app.datasource.username
app.datasource.password
app.datasource.driverClassName
```

Not getting the reason for this behavior

Comment: Why is it even using Hikari of you have a datasource in JNDI? You should be using a JNDI lookup and not HikariCP. So show the code that constructs the datasource for the application.

Comment: @M.Deinum added the code for datasource configuration

Comment: Which properties are you using, also please add the fact that you are using Spring Boot to your question/tags.

Comment: @M.Deinum had specified in question that it is a Spring Boot App, updated properties

Comment: Why specify those properties while you want to use JNDI? What is it that you want? Use the datasource defined in tomcat, or configure a new one?

Comment: @M.Deinum
JNDI datasource configuration is done at tomcat server, used by other deployed applications.
For a specific Spring Boot application, have configured datasource as mentioned above (using properties)

Both data-sources are pointing to common database.

Can the existing configuration/ connections have an effect here

Comment: If that isn't related to your question (you don't want to use JNDI) then why make it part of your question. What you should do is define a bean of type `DataSourceProperties` bind the variables and in the `appDataSource` method use those properties to create the datasource.

Comment: Could you please explain the difference it'll make.
My main confusion is, why does the application with same configuration works fine  after server restart? 

Also, I am facing this issue sporadically, sometimes the application gets deployed properly in first attempt only

Comment: If you use JNDI and redeploy things will be stopped leading to issues, if you use local datasource, it also gets closed but that isn't an issue. So there is a major difference in using or not using JNDI (without a proper config). The fact that you included JNDI leads people (like me) to think you want to use JNDI instead of a local configured datasource and thus a diferent solution path.

Comment: yes got that :)

restating:
I am deploying a Spring Boot App war on external tomcat. Sometimes, it shows error as:
dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required
which gets resolved on server restart.

Datasource is configured as:
@Bean(name = "datasource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.datasource")
  public DataSource appDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

Not getting the reason for this behavior

Comment: Define a `DataSourceProperties` annotate that with `@Bean` and `@ConfigurationProperties` and reference that from your datasource method.